# JS validation with Safari

Tags: javascript

I am using the JS to validate a form on submit. It works fine in Crome, opera. But in Safari it is not working anymore. Safari version 5.1.9 on Mac OSX 10.6.8. Any help?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function validateForm()
    {
        var nrv=document.forms["form1"]["Bchq_amont"].value;
        if (nrv==null || nrv=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("Bchq_amont").style.backgroundColor="orange";
            return false;
        }

        totalvalue = 0;
        for (x=1; x<12; x++)
        { 
            totalvalue += parseInt(document.getElementById("rcv_amount_"+x).value);
        }

        if(parseInt(document.getElementById("Bchq_amont").value) !== totalvalue)
        { 
            alert ("Received amount and bill amounts are not matching"); 
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Does the safari console report any errors?

Comment: how is `validateForm` being executed? - i'm assuming there is an event listener somewhere; to what event is it listening?

Comment: Safary does not response to any of those condition. It submit the form on click.

Comment: How did you attach `validateForm` as a handler?

Comment: <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't told us what the problem is. What isn't working..?

One potential problem is that `totalvalue` has not been declared with `var`. Change that line to...

```
var totalvalue = 0;
```

Comment: wouldn't that just run one time?

Comment: sorry for typo it should be 12. but still same result.

Comment: And what is the result?